# MongoDB-C and BSON

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-c

I wonder if it's possible to retrieve the content of a MongoDB collection under the BSON format ? That is to say retrieve a result like `{"name" : "John","age" : 24}` in the `"tutorial.persons"` collection when the field `_id` is equal to "1" for example.
PS : I use driver-c

Comment: Sure, that's what the driver does, but the driver then deserializes results from BsOn, your own could wouldn't have to do it.

Comment: I just would like to get a mongodb query result in the form of a chain {"name" : "John","age" : 24} !
Is that possible ?